# when i click on "DONE" button on softkeybord how to go next activity android

Tags: android

when i click on softkeyboard my keyboard getdown or hide but i want to go to next activity when i click on "done " button on keyboard of android.so how to do it?

and my next qus is if i have 2 edit box in my layout when i click on first edit box then in my soft keyboard "next " would appear for going to next text box and when i go to second text box it change to "done".
   thanks in advance....

x

Answer (score 5):

Its is better to add some button in the layout as all android phones dont provide a consistent behaviour when using imeoptions.

This seems to be a bug. Different manufacturers make a customized keyboard for their phone which may not completely behave as the android standard keyboard. This issue has been raised before. Most people overcome this issue by either overiding the onKey event or using a TextWatcher class. A bug has been filed about this

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2882

You can use a listener to check for imeoptions

```
incomeInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    //Do your stuff here
                    return true;  // mark the event as consumed
                }
            return false;
            }
}
```

Comment: is it not possible to go next activity class by clicking on android soft kayboard "done " button?actually i want to open both of the option means user can choose any one either  from keyboard of from layout done button.so how to do with softkeyboard?

Comment: ive update my answer. Just keep an alternative if imeoptions dont work

Comment: not working :( actually i had change android soft keyboard button to "NEXT" using android:imeOptions="actionNext" and i want when i click on it go to next activity,but NEXT button i think use for go to next edit text box in android so how to go next activity on clicking of next in soft keyboard ?thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement OnEditorActionListener interface.

Code looks like :

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnEditorActionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
}

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        startActivity(new Intent());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: not working :( actually i had change android soft keyboard button to "NEXT" using        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
 and i want when i click on it go to next activity,but NEXT button i think use for go to next edit text box in android so how to go next activity on clicking of next in soft keyboard ?thanks

Comment: Use this code.....        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
        startActivity(new Intent());
        return true;
    }

Comment: not any effect when i click on software keyboard "Done" button on android emulator except it goes down when i click on it,why ?means why it is not throwing to other acvity means as simple ui view button work pls help...

Comment: Put a log inside onEditorAction(). And check whether it is executing or not?

Comment: we need to add
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this)
Then its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnKeyListener with your second EditText and in onKey method do something like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{       
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    performYourAction();    

  return false;
}
```

I hope it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: hey how we get to know that it is for only for done button press on softkeyboard?

Comment: not working :( actually i had change android soft keyboard button to "NEXT" using android:imeOptions="actionNext" and i want when i click on it go to next activity,but NEXT button i think use for go to next edit text box in android so how to go next activity on clicking of next in soft keyboard ?thanks

Comment: Look for Next key's keyCode like in KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER Or I think you should let Button be what it was and then try.